# How to compute greatest distance between polygon centroid and edge

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

I have a SpatialPolygons(DataFrame) object, e.g. `SpP`

```
library(sp)    
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
```

I would like to, for each polygon, calculate the greatest distance between its centroid (`coordinates(SpP)`) to any other point within the same polygon (I assume this furtherest away point will be on the edge?).

Can someone show me how to do that?

Comment: The furthest point will always be a vertex, so compute all the centroid-vertex distances and take the max.

Comment: @Spacedman would you mind giving me a function?

Comment: Sorry, was busy when I read this and thought I'd correct your assumption about the point being on an edge. Thought that might have helped you code a solution yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function I created that for a given polygon calculates the centroid, and the uses basic geometry to find with point is furthest from the centroid, returning its coordinates:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)

Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Srs2=Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
spPol=SpatialPolygons(list(Srs2))

find_furthest_point=function(polygon){
  coords=fortify(polygon)[,c(1:2)]  
  center=as.data.frame(gCentroid(polygon))
  longs=coords[,1]
  lats=coords[,2]

  dist_fx=function(long, lat, center=center){
    dist=sqrt((long-center[1])^2+(lat-center[2])^2)
    return(dist)
  }
  dists=mapply(dist_fx, longs, lats, MoreArgs=list(center))
  furthest_index=as.integer(which(dists==max(dists)))
  furthest=coords[furthest_index,]  
  return(furthest)
}

find_furthest_point(Sr2)
```

Comment: fortify is just a way to extract data from a polygon into a dataframe

Comment: `fortify` (for `Polygons` objects) comes from `ggplot2`, so do `library(ggplot2)` before, or edit the function to `ggplot2::fortify(.....)`. This code also runs for `SpatialPolygons*` objects like `SpP` in your question.

Comment: NOOOO!!! The mean of the coordinates is **NOT** the centroid! Use `sp` method `coordinates(x)` or `rgeos::gCentroid`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, @Spacedman! I spaced out and was thinking of the centroid of the point vertices, not the polygon...